# "Syntax error, unexpected '&'" ao chamar a função exec

Tags: php

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Executar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        exec( 'Done.exe', &$resultado);
        echo $resultado;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Não está funcionando o comando `exec`, como faço para habilitá-lo?

Comment: Removi as tags HTML, CSS, JavaScript e Node porque não vi relação alguma com a pergunta. Se existir uma relação, recomendo que edite a pergunta detalhando melhor o problema.

Comment: E com base em que você afirma que o `exec` não está funcionando? Deu algum erro? Qual? O que `Done.exe` faz? Ele está no mesmo diretório? O usuário possui permissão para executá-lo? Quais são as últimas mensagens no arquivo de log do seu servidor PHP?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Executar\index.php on line 8

Comment: O arquivo está na mesma pasta do index.php

Comment: Para passar uma variável como referência no PHP apenas o argumento da função precisa indicar o `&`. Você não precisa indicar isso na chamada da função, então faça apenas `exec('Done.exe', $resultado)`

Comment: O arquivo Done.exe executar um jogo em C++ que eu programei e o erro que dar é esse: syntax error, unexpected '&', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Executar\index.php on line 8

Answer (score 1):

Vide [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.pass.php):

> **Nota**: Não há o sinal de referência na chamada da função - apenas nas definições de função. As definições de função, sozinhas, são suficientes para passar o argumento por referência. A partir do PHP 5.3.0 você receberá um alerta de "call-time pass-by-reference" está obsoleto quando usar o & na em chamadas de função: foo(&$a);. A partir do PHP 5.4.0, passagem por referência na chamada foi removido, e usar isso causará um erro fatal.

Ou seja, apenas a assinatura da função que deve indicar que a passagem será feita por referência e não por valor. A partir da versão 5.4 as chamadas utilizando o caractere `&` causarão um erro de sintaxe como você obteu.

Ou seja, na chamada de `exec` basta fazer:

```
exec('Done.exe', $resultado);
```

Mesmo a variável não existindo no contexto ela será criada para receber o valor definido pela função.

Comment: Se eu colocar isso em um servidor, irá ser executado na máquina do servidor ou no computador da pessoa?

Comment: @SchillerDrummond No servidor, sempre.

Comment: Agora como vou infectar minhas vítimas com esse comando :(

Comment: @SchillerDrummond Não vai...